# Need argument-less constructor for subclass, but superclass doesn't have it

Tags: java, inheritance

OOP beginner here... I have a superclass named Rectangle, that has a constructor that accepts int height and int width as arguments. My mission is to create an improved Rectangle subclass, among other things equipped with a constructor that doesn't need arguments.

So, how do I do it without messing with the superclass?

```
public class BetterRectangle extends Rectangle
{
    public BetterRectangle(int height, int width)
    {
        super(height,width);
    }

    public BetterRectangle()
    {
            width = 50;
            height = 50; 
    }
}
```

Which gives me "Implicit super constructor is undefined". Apparently I NEED to call the superclass constructor. But with what? Just random values, later to be overwritten?

Comment: another issue is you don't have instance variables for width, height, so that assignment also fails.

Comment: @Nambari They could be defined in `Rectangle` as non-`private` members.

Comment: @GriffeyDog: If that is the case, I think setting values again using constructor is redundant right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
public BetterRectangle()
{
        super(50, 50); // Call the superclass constructor with 2 arguments 
}
```

Or:

```
public BetterRectangle()
{
        this(50, 50); // call the constructor with 2 arguments of BetterRectangle class.
}
```

You cannot use your code as the first line in a constructor is a call to super() or this(). If there is no call to super() or this(), then the call is implicit. Your code is equivalent to:

```
public BetterRectangle()
{
        super(); // Compile error: Call superclass constructor without arguments, and there is no such constructor in your superclass.
        width = 50;
        height = 50; 
}
```

Comment: Sure, but if I don't want the rectangle to be 50x50 but some user defined value?

Comment: Isn't that what the other ctor is for?

Comment: If you don't pass arguments, how users can pass their values? In a no-argument constructor, you need to provide default values.

Comment: Yes but I want the BetterRectangle class to ask for user input for height and width if main should happen to create a new BetterRectangle object without passing height/width as arguments.

Comment: You can of course construct a `BetterRectangle` with default values, and ask for `height` and `width` during execution. Then you can modify the default values with the new ones. But you need to provide default values as the superclass requires this type of initialization.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist you can't do the prompting in the constructor.  Instead separate the data class and the behaviour class.  Do the prompting where appropriate and then create the instance of BetterRectangle when you have the parameters.  Also, the [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29) pattern may be applicable to your use.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist  PS.  A constructor should not have side effects, nor prompt, nor perform I/O, nor anything else other than initialize the fields of the object.  The other behaviour belongs in other methods and/or classes but not in a constructor.